# Excel side by side comparison with C# Excel Interop

Tags: c#, excel, excel-interop

Attempting to load two Excel workbooks side by side with C# using Excel interop.

I've tried a variety of ways, but I have been unable to get this to work. I've gotten it to work with Word documents.

```
Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application ExcelApp = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application();
ExcelApp.Visible = true;
Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Workbook doc1 = ExcelApp.Workbooks.Open(fileToOpen.ToString());
Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Workbook doc2 = ExcelApp.Workbooks.Open(file2ToOpen.ToString());
var result = doc1.Windows.CompareSideBySideWith(doc2.Windows[1].Caption);
```

Both workbooks are opening fine, but then I'm getting below exception on the `CompareSideBySideWith` method:

```
'Invalid index. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x8002000B (DISP_E_BADINDEX))'
```

I think I have the wrong string for the parameter, but I can't figure out what to put for WindowName. I've tried the document name, sheet name, full path, with or without the extension - not sure what else to try.

Updated - revised working code, with assistance from Slai:

```
Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application ExcelApp = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application();
ExcelApp.Visible = true;
Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Workbook doc1 = ExcelApp.Workbooks.Open(fileToOpen.ToString());
Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Workbook doc2 = ExcelApp.Workbooks.Open(file2ToOpen.ToString());
doc1.Activate(); 
var result = ExcelApp.Windows.CompareSideBySideWith(doc2.Windows[1].Caption);
```

Comment: What about `.Windows[0]` ?

Comment: Windows [0] throws an error, appears that arrays start at 1 here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`doc2.Windows` is not in the `doc1.Windows` collection. `ExcelApp.Windows` can be used instead:

```
var wb2 = ExcelApp.Workbooks.Open(file2ToOpen.ToString());
var wb1 = ExcelApp.Workbooks.Open(fileToOpen.ToString()); // wb1 is now active

bool result = ExcelApp.Windows.CompareSideBySideWith(wb2.Windows[1].Caption);
```

The Record Macro feature can be used to compare the generated VBA code for hints.

Comment: Ah! The method name matches the method for Microsoft Word, but the implementation is _so_ different. This resolved it for me. I'll post the updated working code in my original answer, you can paste it into your answer if you'd like.